# The entity type requires a primary key to be defined - A primary key is the ONLY thing that's defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add a model to a project I've been working on, and today I'm running into an issue where every time I try to add a migration I get the error "The entity type '_____' requires a primary key to be defined". The model has a property called "ID", and I've tried adding the [Key] attribute to it, and I've even tried removing everything except the ID property and it still won't work.

Here is the model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace APD_Remastered_Ideas.Models
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id;
        public string address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Edit: I've also tried writing the migration myself:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace APD_Remastered_Ideas.Data.Migrations
{
    public partial class addTestModelToDb : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "TestModel",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_TestModel", x => x.Id);
            });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "TestModel");
        }
    }
}
```

And I've also tried manually creating the table in SSMS. In all of my other projects, adding models this way still works. However in this project, I'm unable to add any.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I forgot to put `{get; set; }` after the Id property. Here's the corrected model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace APD_Remastered_Ideas.Models
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
    }
}
```